# How to flatMap to database in Apache Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Apache Flink trying to get JSON records from Kafka to InfluxDB, splitting them from one JSON record into multiple InfluxDB points in the process.

I found the `flatMap` transform and it feels like it fits the purpose. Core code looks like this:

```java
DataStream<InfluxDBPoint> dataStream = stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<JsonConsumerRecord, InfluxDBPoint>() {
    @Override
    public void flatMap(JsonConsumerRecord record, Collector<InfluxDBPoint> out) throws Exception {
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = //...

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            // extract point from input
            InfluxDBPoint point = //...

            out.collect(point);
        }
    }
});
```

For some reason, I only get one of those collected points streamed into the database.

Even when I print out all mapped entries, it seems to work just fine: `dataStream.print()` yields:

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.influxdb.InfluxDBPoint@144fd091
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.influxdb.InfluxDBPoint@57256d1
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.influxdb.InfluxDBPoint@28c38504
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.influxdb.InfluxDBPoint@2d3a66b3
```

Am I misunderstanding `flatMap` or might there be some bug in the Influx connector?

Comment: If you see all the results that expect when you print the stream it might be a problem in the InfluxSink. But from what you show here it seems like you are using flatmap in the right way.

Comment: @TobiSH yeah, I just created a subclass of InfluxSink and could verify that all the points are arriving in the `invoke` method. So definitely seems like a sink problem at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually related to the fact that a series (defined by its tagset and measurement [as seen here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/2055)) in Influx can only have one point *per time*, therefore even though my fields differed, the final point overwrote all previous points with the same time value.